# Add array to another array of larger size

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array `A` of size 5000, and a smaller array `B` of arbitrary size but smaller than `A`. My smaller array always produces new values which I do not want to loose hence I add them to the array `A` and continue, however I am stuck because whenever I try to copy the smaller to the larger instead of appending from where it was left of it completely erases the prior values and array `A` becomes equal to array `B`.

```
offset = offset + B.length;
System.arraycopy(B, 0, A, offset, B.length);
```

This statement is in a loop that updates `B` everytime.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you show the complete code in the loop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a much better idea to use `ArrayList`s instead. An `ArrayList` is essentially an array with infinite capacity. You can just keep adding stuff and it will never run out of room. It also adds things to the end for you, without you having to compute the end index. So, if you make `A` and `B` `ArrayList`s, then your code becomes the following:

```
A.addAll(B);
```

That's it.

Comment: yess finally tried with arraylist, helps in increasing my array dynamilcally.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a look at this link, and look at the section explaining the `length` parameter: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html. I think your problem resides in the length argument being passed in.

Also the statement `offset = offset + B.length;` should come after the loop, because you are passing in a variable size `A.length + B.length`, as supposed to just `B.length`, which is were you want to place array `B`.

the argument where `A` is is the destination array. So you have to redeclare `A` to be the length of `offset`.

Hope this helps.